# Getting Values from XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML File that is filled with values that look like  :

```
<property name ="Web Application" value="\Fxnet2\Web\webpl\" />
<property name="Web Service" value="\FXnet2\Web\FXnet_SC_WS\" />
```

For each line i would like to import the name into one string (Lets call it serviceName) and the value in a different one (Lets call it servicePath)

I got around 250 lines of the sort in the xml , is it possible to do it in the current xml format? and if it does how ? , or should i change the format of my list?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Yes, it's very simple to do that in your current XML format. I would suggest using LINQ to XML - you could easily transform a document in that form into a list of name/value pairs. I suggest you try it, and then edit your question once you run into an actual problem.

Comment: Another possibility would be to create a datatype `property` and deserialize the file into an array of `property`, then access the data in code.

Comment: I was thinking about creating a class named project that contains the variables to contain the name and the value and create a new object for every line , sorry if my questions look stupid , i`m new to C# programming

Comment: @user3521610 yes you can do that, and deserialize your xml to List<Project> , or you can also read it efficiently using linq-to-xml running over Elements() of the xDocument.

Comment: @JonSkeet 's big reputation card is creating formatting issue in SO :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get all  nodes and access their attributes in a loop. In the example below I'm adding the values of both attributes to 2 different arrays that you can easily manipulate later.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("yourfile.xml");
XmlNodeList usernodes = doc.SelectNodes("//property");

//Declare arrays
List<string> serviceName = new List<string>();
List<string> servicePath = new List<string>();

//iterate through all elements found
foreach (XmlNode usernode in usernodes)
{
    serviceName.Add(usernode.Attributes["name"].Value);
    serviceName.Add(usernode.Attributes["value"].Value);
}
```

Comment: This example is in C# but you can easily transport it to other programming languages.

Comment: Wont it just create 2 seperate arrays in which 1 will include all the ServiceNames and the other will include servicPaths ? What if i want to add more variables ? for example create a class with different variables and create separate object for every line in the xml ?

Comment: Fox example , in my xml each value is a path , i want to go to this path and extract a list of all the DLL Files in this location which i would like to insert into a array so in the future i can compare files etc... , when using your code i will get a array filled with project names and array filled with paths , but if adding array of dll`s i will only get an array filled with the DLL list of the first location .

Comment: I see what you mean. It wasn't clear in your question that you wanted to access the dlls in that path with the code, I see you figured that out below.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to Do it in the end

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Service> services;

            using(StreamReader file = File.OpenText("c:\\projects.xml"))
            {

                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);
                services = (from node in doc.Root.Elements("property")
                               select new Service
                               {
                                   serviceName = node.Attribute("name").Value,
                                   servicePath = node.Attribute("value").Value,
                                   dllFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles( "servicePath", "*.dll" ),
                               }).ToList<Service>();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using XML Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                "<Root>" +
                    "<property name =\"Web Application\" value=\"\\Fxnet2\\Web\\webpl\" />" +
                    "<property name=\"Web Service\" value=\"\\FXnet2\\Web\\FXnet_SC_WS\" />" +
                "</Root>";

            XElement root = XElement.Parse(input);

            var results = root.Descendants("property").Select(x => new {
                name = x.Attribute("name").Value,
                value = x.Attribute("value").Value
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
​
```